# line 679, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'

Tags: python, bots, slack

I am currently trying to create a slack bot using Python, I keep receiving this error. I think my python-dotenv package is not reading my environment variables properly however I have no idea why this error keeps popping up whenever I run my code. Some help would be appreciated.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from slack_sdk.web.client import WebClient

env_path = Path('.', '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
client = WebClient(token=slack_token)
```

```
in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'
```

Comment: "why this error keeps popping up" - there's no environment variable called `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN`. Are you sure the `.env` file is being loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have a .env file in the same folder as my code. It should be loaded correctly because when I do load_dotenv by itself no errors appear.

Comment: maybe first check `print(env_path)` and current working directory `print( os.getcwd() )` - maybe it starts in different folder. You can also check what you have in this folder `print( os.listdir() )`